# Restrict the requests coming to my webpage based on their url in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, curl, request

I have to restrict the users accessing my webpage based on the url from where the request is coming to my webpage. I am able to get the url from where the request is coming using

> $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

As i know the `HTTP_REFERER` is a header which is sent by the client, most browsers default behavior is to send it, but users can disable it or even send a different referer header. So is there any way to do the proper validation of request based on their url.

Comment: You could just check the `HTTP_REFERER`  with the understanding that it's easy to bypass this check. I feel like you're trying to do something that makes no sense in the context of a stateless protocol. Also CORS restriction is a feature which is meant to protect the **users** not the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if the user has set the browser to modify the referrer header, there's no way for PHP to discern whether or not the request has come from a certain website.

Blocking traffic from a URL, although easy to do - cannot ever be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but, for others looking for a more recent answer there are commands that can be added on nginx/apache servers to restrict access from other hosts to local paths, establish the number of requests allowed per minute, etc.

However, if you don't have access to the server/directory configuration, then Laravel can still offer you some techniques to manage this issue.

One is to create a new middleware to limit access to the requesting hosts.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class checkHosts
{
   /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
    */
   public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
   {
      if ($request->getHost() != '<host_name>') {
         return response('You do not have access rights to this content.', 403);
      }
      return $next($request);
   }
}
```

Do not forget to add this middleware to the file: `app\Http\Kernel.php` so that it takes immediate effect for every request made to your end point.